# Which of the following two calls is sure to be valid and why?

Tags: c

```
MAC(++a, b);
```

or

```
mac(++a, b);
```

with the first being a macro call and the second being an analogous function call.

It's a review question at the end of a chapter in a C Programming book. I don't think either are SURE to be valid and perhaps it is a trick question but I'm not sure because I don't really see how a macro call is any different than the function call in this instance

Comment: wait, what?! Is this homework or a question from a quiz? *what do you think, and why*?

Comment: Ask yourself... what is a macro??, and you have the answer of your question

Comment: It's a review question at the end of a chapter in a C Programming book. I don't think either are SURE to be valid and perhaps it is a trick question but I'm not sure because I don't really see how a macro call is any different than the function call in this instance.

Comment: If the macro just call the function, is exactly the same

Comment: The question makes no sense. Firstly, there's no such thing as "macro call". Secondly, whatever that macro gets substituted with can easily be perfectly intentional. So, what is "valid" in this case? There's no way to say anything about knowing the intent.

Comment: Why is the question unclear? It asks which one between a function and a macro with the same "interface" implementing _ostensibly_ the _same thing_ is guaranteed to be valid. It is evidently the function, since a macro implementation could cause multiple expansions of the side-effecting `++a` between the same two sequence points, something known to be UB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The guaranteed-valid version is probably

```
mac(++a, b)
```

because the macro version `MAC` may evaluate its operands multiple times. Take for instance

```
#define MAC(a, b) (a + a + b)
```

In that case, `MAC(++a, b)` will expand to

```
(++a + ++a + b)
```

which is undefined since it modifies twice `a` between two sequence points.

On the other hand, a function call evaluates its arguments exactly once, always.

Comment: Where that magic MAC comes from?

Comment: Thank you very well explained.

Comment: @DGomez I'm sorry can you explain?

Comment: I mean, you're assuming the value of the macro, but is not specified anywhere

Comment: @DGomez: The author said that, "with the first being a macro call and the second being an analogous function call." he don't need know how the macro is exactly defined, just that it's a macro.

Comment: @Jack Yeah, you're right, i thought the OP asked the question with some example code, not in a generic way